# How to convert my python program to a Tkinter with entry fields, tkinter canvas and start button?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am sending 8 parameters to Arduino using a python program. I receive 3 output from Arduino namely time, voltage and current. These data sets are recevied a specified number of times based on the input parameters and saved in a CSV file. I want to create a Tkinter based GUI where user can provide inputs to the CV function in the program and the outputs from Arduino gets plotted in real time.

The follwing is my python code

```py
import time
import serial
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import csv
import os
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")


ser = serial.Serial('COM4',timeout=0.1)
ser.baudrate = 115200

# Create a tkinter root window
root = tk.Tk()

# root window title and dimension
root.title("Welcome to DIY_VERSION1")

# Set geometry(widthxheight)
root.geometry('350x200')

def CV(name,input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7):

    global ser,Receivedarray

    now = datetime.now()
    NAME=name+str(now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S"))
    with open(NAME+'.csv', 'a') as file:
        file.write("Time,Voltage,Current \n")

    ####SENDING PARAMETERS######################
    dac_start=round(input1*.819)
    dac_end=round(input2*.819)
    up_limit=round(input3*.819)
    lo_limit=round(input4*.819)
    inc=round(input5*.819)
    interval=input5*1000/input6
    no_of_cycle=input6
    relay=input7
    
    param='<'+str(dac_start)+','+str(dac_end)+','+str(up_limit)+','+str(lo_limit)  \
    +','+str(inc)+','+str(interval)+','+str(no_of_cycle)+','+str(relay)+'>'
    print(param)
    ser.write(param.encode())
    
    #######################################  
Time=[]
V=[]
I=[]   
# Loop through and collect data as it is available
def read_from_arduino(ser):
    e=0
    while True:
        # Read the line
        if ser.inWaiting()>0:
            response=ser.readline()          ### Receiving confirmation from arduino
            dataArray = response.decode("utf-8").strip('\r\n')
            
            if dataArray=='':
                continue
            # Parse the line
            if (dataArray == '<'):
                 print("START\n")
                 break
            else:
                 continue
             
        else:
            e=e+1
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if e>100:
                print("Data not received")
                sys.exit()
                
    while True:
       
        try:
            if ser.inWaiting()>0:
                response=ser.readline()          ### Receiving confirmation from arduino
                dataArray = response.decode("utf-8").strip('\r\n')
                
                if dataArray=='':
                    continue  
                
                if (dataArray ==">"):
                   print("\ncOMPLETE")
                   break
               
                else:
                    values=dataArray.split(',')
                    T = float(values[0]) / 1000
                     # Measures actual voltage of the working electrode in volts
                    voltage = -(float(values[1])+.012) 
                     # Current conversion from voltage measured in milliAmps
                    current = (float(values[2]) +.015)
                    print("Time: "+str(T)+' Voltage: '+str(voltage)+'Current: '+str(current),end='\r') 
                    
                    with open(NAME+'.csv',mode="a")as file:
                        file.write(f"{T},{voltage},{current}\n")
      
                    V.append(voltage)          
                    I.append(current)
                    Time.append(T)

        except IndexError:
            continue
       
        except ValueError:
            e=e+1
            if e>1000:
                sys.exit()
            else: 
                continue
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            ser.write("222".encode())
            break


# Create input fields for the user to enter the parameters
        # Input fields
name_label = tk.Label( text="Name: ")
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
name_entry = tk.Entry()
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

input1_label = tk.Label(text="INPUT1 ")
input1_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
input1_entry = tk.Entry()
input1_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        
input2_label = tk.Label( text="INPUT2")
input2_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
input2_entry = tk.Entry()
input2_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

input3_label = tk.Label( text="INPUT3 ")
input3_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
input3_entry = tk.Entry()
input3_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

input4_label = tk.Label( text="INPUT4 ")
input4_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
input4_entry = tk.Entry()
input4_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

input5_label = tk.Label(text="INPUT5 ")
input5_label.grid(row=5 , column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
input5_entry = tk.Entry()
input5_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

input6_label = tk.Label(text="INPUT6 ")
input6_label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
input6_entry = tk.Entry()
input6_entry.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

input7_label = tk.Label(text="INPUT7 ")
input7_label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
input7_entry = tk.Entry()
input7_entry.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

#create a matplotlibfigure and tkinter canvas plot
figure= Figure()
canvas= FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure,root)     
   
# function called PERIODICALLY
def update_plot(canvas,root):
# Clear the previous plot
    #canvas.delete("all")
    
    name = name_entry.get()
    input1 = float(input1_entry.get())
    input2 = float(input2_entry.get())
    input3 = float(input3_entry.get())
    input4 = float(input4_entry.get())
    input5 = float(input5_entry.get())
    input6 = float(input6_entry.get())
    input7 = int(input7_entry.get())
    
    # call your function
    time, voltage, current = CV(name,input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7)
    output_list1 =[]
    output_list2 =[]
    output_list3 =[]
    t = output_list1.append(time)
    v = output_list2.append(voltage)
    i = output_list3.append(current)

    figure1 = Figure(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=100)
    subplot1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
    subplot1.set_title('Voltage vs Current')
    subplot1.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)')
    subplot1.set_ylabel('Current (uA)')

    figure2 = Figure(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=100)
    subplot2 = figure2.add_subplot(111)
    subplot2.set_title('Time vs Voltage')
    subplot2.set_xlabel('Time')
    subplot2.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')

    canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1)
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=5, padx=5, pady=5)
    canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure2)
    canvas2.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5, column=2, rowspan=5, padx=5, pady=5)
        
    # Redraw the canvas with the updated plot
    subplot1.clear()
    subplot1.scatter(v, i)
    subplot1.set_title('Voltage vs Current')
    subplot1.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)')
    subplot1.set_ylabel('Current (uA)')
    
    subplot2.clear()
    subplot2.plot(t, v)
    subplot2.set_title('Time vs Voltage')
    subplot2.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
    subplot2.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')
        
    canvas1.draw()
    canvas2.draw()
    
button=tk.Button(root, text= 'START', command = lambda: update_plot(canvas,root))
button.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()
```

A GUI with entry fields for parameters and a START button is created but when I provide the inputs. I get an errors which says

```
File "C:\Users\Veeruchi\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Veeruchi\OneDrive\Desktop\MTP2\Final Docs\final_tkinter.py", line 274, in <lambda>
    button=tk.Button(root, text= 'START', command = lambda: update_plot(canvas,root))
  File "C:\Users\Veeruchi\OneDrive\Desktop\MTP2\Final Docs\final_tkinter.py", line 233, in update_plot
    time, voltage, current = CV(name,start_voltage,end_voltage,upper_limit,lower_limit,step_size,scan_rate,no_of_cycle)
  File "C:\Users\Veeruchi\OneDrive\Desktop\MTP2\Final Docs\final_tkinter.py", line 58, in CV
    with open(NAME+'.csv', 'a') as file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'cv20-01-2023-15:30:56.csv'
```

Comment: Change your pattern in `NAME=name+str(now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S"))` remove the semicolon, to make a valid filename

Answer (score 0):

Some special characters are not allowed when opening/writing/reading a file, my solution is something like using the replace function to make the filename 'readable', then apply...
Here's an example

Your error is in 'with open', if you want to add information to the existing file, the idea is to use 'a' as a parameter, but from what I understand you are wanting to create files with new names with the time of the result, so use 'w' as a parameter to write a new file.
`with open(NAME+'.csv', 'a')`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

app = tk.Tk()


def create_csv():
    now = str(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
    now = now.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_').replace('.', '_').replace(':', '_')
    print('writing: ', now)
    with open(f'{now}.csv', 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(now))


button = tk.Button(app, text='Save', command=create_csv)
button.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: After correcting this, I am getting another error as follows: 1) line 276, in <lambda>
    button=tk.Button(root, text= 'START', command = lambda: update_plot(canvas,root))         2) line 235, in update_plot
    T, voltage, current = read_from_arduino(ser,NAME)
NameError: name 'NAME' is not defined

Comment: My script does not use lambda.